# Connecting sendgrid credentials to php.ini

Tags: php, sendgrid

I have installed php and mysql on ubuntu 20 and i have also installed sendmail so that i can use `mail()` like

```
<?php
// the message
$msg = "First line of text\nSecond line of text";

// use wordwrap() if lines are longer than 70 characters
$msg = wordwrap($msg,70);

// send email
mail("email@example.com","My subject",$msg);
?>
```

My php.ini section that deals with email looks like this

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = me@example.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
;sendmail_path =

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail().
;mail.force_extra_parameters =

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
mail.add_x_header = Off

; The path to a log file that will log all mail() calls. Log entries include
; the full path of the script, line number, To address and headers.
;mail.log =
; Log mail to syslog (Event Log on Windows).
;mail.log = syslog
```

My sendgrid details necessary to send email are like this

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=apikey
MAIL_PASSWORD=6fggd_long_key
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=info@example.com
```

How can i connect my sendgrid to php.ini so that `mail()` can send email via sendgrid?.

Comment: As far as I know, PHP's mail function doesn't support authentication when using SMTP, so the best bet would be to use something like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) instead of PHP's low level `mail()`-function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the reasons that I outlined [in this tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/blog/send-emails-php-2023), I wouldn't use PHP's mail function to send email. It's likely more of a hassle than it's worth.

Rather, I'd use one of the libraries outlined in that tutorial, such as [Symfony Mailer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html) or [the Official Twilio SendGrid PHP API Library](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/tree/main).